# EasyPHP Devserver 17

Tags: easyphp

Is there an easier way to connect to my localhost than using my the whole directory structure

**e.i.:**

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2425vc11x86x180404190153/htdocs/CCB%20Waterloo/index.html.
```

Still need help,
Your suggestion for http://localhost/CCB%20Waterloo/index.html doesn't work get refused to connect
(This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost CCB Waterloo index
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE)

Not used to the newer version. Have an error with dashboard that MSVCR100.dll not found. Then the Easy PHP server at 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Comment: `http://localhost/CCB%20Waterloo/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

For your MSVCR problem, fisrt, read this : http://www.easyphp.org/faq_devserver.php#collapse001

And when EasyPHP Devserver is running properly, open tyour file with : `http://127.0.0.1/CCB%20Waterloo/index.html`. If the port is different from 80, 88 for example, use `http://127.0.0.1:88/CCB%20Waterloo/index.html`